# Getting TD value from TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm new to Javascript and I'm having trouble to get the value from a `<td>`.

Here is some code to illustrate the problem:

```
    <div id="lista_ativo">
    <table class="tabela-basica" width="100%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
          <thead>

            <tr>
              <th width="35px">ID</th>
              <th width="200px">Cliente</th>
              <th width="200px">Nome</th>
              <th width="35px">OAB</th>
              <th width="50px">Estado</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <tr class="{classe_row}">
              <td data-id="{andamentos_ativos.clienteid}">{andamentos_ativos.clienteid}</td>
              <td>{andamentos_ativos.cliente}</td>
              <td>{andamentos_ativos.nome}</td>
              <td>{andamentos_ativos.oab} / {andamentos_ativos.oab_uf}</td>
              <td>{andamentos_ativos.estados}</td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
$("#lista_ativo").delegate("tr", "click", function() {
    var idbcorporativo = $(this).attr("data-id");
    console.log(idbcorporativo);
});
```

I need the `data-id` from the first `<td>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go from the tr to the th.

And then reference to the first child beginning by 0.

```
  var idbcorporativo = $(this).children()[0].attr("data-id");
```

Comment: No problem, greethings

Answer (score 2):

you can try using `getAttribute`

```
document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getAttribute("data-id");
```

or with jQuery you can modify your code to

```
$("#lista_ativo").delegate("tbody tr", "click", function() {
    var idbcorporativo = $(this).children().attr("data-id");
    console.log(idbcorporativo);
});
```

here's the [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thM9j/)